# Split by attribute automatically on several layers in QGIS?

Tags: layers, qgis-2, split-by-attribute

I need to do a 2 stage split by attribute, using QGIS 2.0.1-Dufour. After the first split, I got 30 layers.

Is there any way to do the second split automatically? I don't really like the idea to make the split manually.

It would be great to select all the opened layers, and make the split by the - common - attribute with one click. The result would go in a separate directory for each layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, I suggest just concatenating  your two 'split' fields into one, which would give all possible combinations, then just use that column for the split. You could remove the concatenated column when done to clean up the data if that matters.